# How to set visibility of this frame in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer, frame

I have a frame named FiHaStart.
That must close itself and pass another frame named NewPlayer. 
frame NewPlayer is opened but the frame FiHaStart still exist(not closed).
What can I do?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class FiHaStart extends JFrame {
 JFrame start;
 JLabel gif;
 JPanel p1;

 Timer timer;

public  FiHaStart(int seconds){     // We have a gif on the frame it takes 7 seconds
    timer = new Timer();            //The frame will be closed after 7 seconds
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000);

}
```

//The problem is probably here.

```
 class RemindTask extends TimerTask{
    public void run(){
         setVisible(false);

         timer.cancel();
         new NewPlayer();
    }
 }

public FiHaStart() {

  // JLabel backGround = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\new.png"));
  setTitle("FiHa");
  setSize(750, 550);
  setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
  // getContentPane().add(backGround);
  setLayout(null);

  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setVisible(true);
  setResizable(false);

  setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\new.png")));

  setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images\\iconfh.png"));

    gif = new JLabel("");
    ImageIcon ikon=new ImageIcon("images\\giff.gif");
    gif.setIcon(ikon);
    gif.setBounds( 210, 350 , 319,36);
    this.add(gif);

    revalidate();
    repaint();

    new FiHaStart(7);
   }
}
```

Comment: I cant set visibility of this frame false. :/

Comment: post minimal example . all gif code is irrelevant

Answer (score 2):

Why are you calling `new FiHaStart(7)` at the end of your default constructor? Basically you're creating two `FiHaStart` instances at the same time.

Why not just start the `RemindTask` instead of calling `new FiHaStart(7)` in your default constructor. Something like:

```
   public FiHaStart() {
       // other code
       timer = new Timer();            
       timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), 7*1000);
   }
```

You should take a look at how to organize your java class constructors. Usually for your default constructor, the compiler will automatically insert the default constructor of the super class or you explicitly invoke a constructor from same class or from the super class using `super` or `this`, not `new`.

Also, you made the constructor `FiHaStart(double seconds)` as public without initializing the variables inside the instance.

The other problem in your code is it's using a `java.util.Timer`. For scheduling tasks that will interact with swing components, you should use [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2487349/6041964) is a stack overflow post that discussed about it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to simulate the click on x button of the frame. try this : 
yourframe.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(yourframe, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));